# How to extract only list, note & caution elements from proct element and outside proct element wrap with info element using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**
I want to extract only list, note,  caution elements from proct element and outside proct element wrap the extracted elements with info element.

Please check the input and expected output.

Please help me out with the solution.

**

**input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<procstep id="NODE17">
  <graphelem id="NODE18" width="column">
    <graphic graphicname="T2022359" id="NODE19" scale="65"/>
  </graphelem>
  <proct>
    <xref>test xref</xref>
    <p>Clean the contact surfaces on the cylinder head.</p>
    <p> Install:</p>
    <list style="random">
      <li id="NODE20">sealing plates onto the cylinder head using cylinder head bolts and M16 nuts.</li>
    </list>
    <note>test note</note>
    <caution>test caution</caution>
  </proct>
</procstep>
```

**expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<procstep id="NODE17">
  <proct>
    <xref>test xref</xref>
    <p>Clean the contact surfaces on the cylinder head.</p>
    <p> Install</p>
  </proct>
  <info>
    <list style="random">
      <li id="NODE20">sealing plates onto the cylinder head using cylinder head bolts and M16 nuts.</li>
    </list>
    <note>test note</note>
    <caution>test caution</caution>
  </info>
  <info>
    <graphelem id="NODE18" width="column">
      <graphic graphicname="T2022359" id="NODE19" scale="65"/>
    </graphelem>
  </info>
</procstep>
```

**XSL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="rocstep">     
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="*[starts-with(local-name(),'graphelem')]">
        <step>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="proct"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="* except proct"/>
        </step>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am struggling with formatting sorry about that

Comment: Need help with the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's one that may be useful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="procstep"> 
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="proct"/>  
        <xsl:element name="info">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="proct/list|proct/note|proct/caution"/>  
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="info">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="graphelem"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="proct">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xref|p"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However there will be a scenario where note, caution and list will not be available inside proct in that case info element would not be required. How can we handle this with conditions. For ex - If list, caution and note is present in proct then create info to wrap list caution etc. otherwise info element is not required.

Comment: So, wrap the element that contains apply-templates for note, caution and list in a xsl:if instruction.  And test for the presence of any of those elements.